# Ext JS - How to Grok the Syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, extjs

I needed to figure out how to get the value of a field on my form from within a handler function but I didn't know how to reference the field and kept getting errors. I spent time looking at the API, code examples and googling. Finally I found one example which works (I imagine there are others).

Assuming a form named MyForm and a field 'myField'

```
var myVal = myForm.getForm().findField("myField").getValue();
```

Maybe I'm just too new at this, but I don't think it's obvious from looking at the API docs.
So my question is, when you're trying to figure something out, what's your approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Examples, documentation, intuition, and API source code.

Comment: @pixelbobby - Not the first time i've seen Grok as part of a question on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324854/why-is-it-mainly-developers-who-grok-something

Comment: [Interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324854/why-is-it-mainly-developers-who-grok-something#comment-6886436)...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set the id of the field, you can use `Ext.getCmp(id)` to have the ComponentManager look it up. There's also `Ext.getDom(id)` which basically acts as a wrapper to getElementById.

In addition, many event handler functions allow setting the scope of the function itself. The documentation for that event should note which object is setting the scope. You may be able to set the form field as the scope object and use `this.getValue()` but it's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.

To answer the question at hand: the more you code, the more you grok. Ext JS has a bit of a learning curve but the example source code provided in the download is a great place to start. There are several errors and omissions in the documentation though, so the most authoritative place to go for answers is straight into the source. Reading up on JavaScript callbacks doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Man, I hope in the intervening half-year they weren't waiting.